# running function from another php file

Tags: php

I have one `cron` file that is called by the server once a day.
In that cron file I do `require_once()` to another file with functions. In that file I have a `echo` just to let me know it's being called.

Now, the `echo` is called but not a function inside that 2nd file.

cron.php

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

//  external Calendar Sync
$the_file=AC_INLCUDES_ROOT."/ajax/syncExternalCalendar.php";
if(!file_exists($the_file)) die("<b>".$the_file."</b> not found");
else{
    require_once($the_file);
}
// other code
cronSyncExternalCalendar(); // this is ignored? or nothing happens
```

syncExternalCalendar.php

```
echo 'syncExternalCalendar.php loaded'; echo '<br />'; // this echoes
function cronSyncExternalCalendar(){
    echo 'Fired cronSyncExternalCalendar<br />';       // this doesn't(!)
}
```

The external file runs great if I call that function after declaring it (in the same file) and of course commenting it in the cron.php. But I cannot make it run from the cron.php.

Any ideas?

Comment: I just tested the exact same code, only removing `AC_INLCUDES_ROOT`, and it executed just fine

Comment: hmmm, can't see any reason that wouldn't work. If the function didn't exist PHP would complain, so if there're no errors it must be calling the function. You say this works when you call the function from syncExternalCalendar.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have only defined the function. If you want it to run, you need to invoke it.

```
echo 'syncExternalCalendar.php loaded'; echo '<br />'; // this echoes

function cronSyncExternalCalendar(){
    echo 'Fired cronSyncExternalCalendar<br />';       // this doesn't(!)
}

cronSyncExternalCalendar();
```

Comment: Patrick, I do that. As I wrote in the end that works great when I call it in the same file. Like you posted. But I want to call it from the cron.php file. And that doesn't work.

Comment: What are you using `AC_INLCUDES_ROOT` for?

Comment: It's to resolve the path of the file. But that sould be no problem since I get the echo from inside the required file.

Comment: Patrik! My bad! In the code between the require and the function calling I had a if statement with a `die()`. That was "killing it". Thank you for checking this and spending time helping!